# Creating a matrix from a function with multiple arrays without for loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I have the following five arrays:

```
t = np.linspace(0,100,100)
Q = t**2

x = np.linspace(10,20,20)
y = np.linspace(5,8,5)
z = np.linspace(100,125,10)
```

I also define a function as follows:

```
def f(t, x, y, z):
    return (1+x)**3.2 * y**x * np.cos(y**x)*(t-z)
```

Now for each i-th element of `x`, j-th element of `y`, and k-th element of `z`, I want to determine the value that `f(t, x, y, z)` takes at all values of `t`.
I also want to take the 'inner product' with each of these results with the `Q` array.
So what I want to end up with is a 3 dimensional matrix that stores arrays of size `len(t)` with each element (i,j,k) of this matrix equal to `np.sum( Q * f(t, x[i], y[j], z[k]))`.
All of this can be achieved with a for loop as follows:

```
result = np.zeros(len(x)*len(y)*len(z)).reshape((len(x),len(y), len(z)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            intermediate_result = f(t, x[i], y[j], z[k]) #This is an array of length len(t)
            result[i][j][k] = (np.nansum(intermediate_result * Q))**2
```

The problem is that these for loops are very time consuming to compute for larger arrays x, y and z beyond this simplified example, so I am looking for a way to decrease computation time.
Is there an effective way to do this?

Comment: Look at ` p.xi_(x,y,z)`

Comment: Do you mean np.ix_(x,y,z)? Could you explain to me how that works in this case? It doesn't appear quite evident to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop. you can let numpy do the broadcasting by reshaping the parameter variables :

```
result = f(t,x[:,None,None,None],y[:,None,None],z[:,None])

result = np.sum(Q*result,axis=3)
```

note that you could do this inside the function using np.ix_

```
def f(t, x, y, z):
    x,y,z,t = np.ix_(x,y,z,t)
    return (1+x)**3.2 * y**x * np.cos(y**x)*(t-z)
```

The function will return a 4D matrix that you can then process with np.sum :

```
result = np.sum(Q*f(t,x,y,z),axis=3)
```

*This will run noticeably faster than loops (more than 10x faster for this 100 x 20x5x10 example)*

**[EDIT]** Given that a 4D matrix consumes a lot of memory, you will eventually get into another kind of bottleneck as the dimensions get bigger.  You can circumvent this by limiting the matrix to 3 dimensions and manually adding the t dimension in a loop. This ensures that you never use more than twice the size of your resulting 3D matrix:

```
def f2(t, x, y, z):
    x,y,z = np.ix_(x,y,z)
    return (1+x)**3.2 * y**x * np.cos(y**x)*(t-z)

result = np.zeros((x.size,y.size,z.size))
for tn,Qn in zip(t,Q):
    result += f2(tn,x,y,z)*Qn
```

With this approach I was able to obtain the result in 19 seconds for t.size=300 and x,y,z at 256x256x256.  The 4D matrix approach crashed the IDLE shell (probably because of memory overflow) and I didn't have the patience to wait for the original for loops to finish.

*note that this last approach may produce minute differences near the 16th digit of the mantissa when compared to the original solution because of the order in which np.sum() adds the values*

Comment: Looks good. Here's your solution compared to OP's: https://rextester.com/VPKX47287 where `np.array_equal(result, result2)` renders `True`.

Comment: That's indeed a significant improvement. I also had some issues with my computer freezing with your first solution for larger arrays, but the edit fixes that. Could you also show what this solution looks like if I wanted to calculate `result[i][j][k] = (np.nansum(intermediate_result * Q))**2` instead? Let me update my post to this.

Comment: Never mind, it appears to be as simple as just adding `result *= result` at the end. This doesn't take the nansum into account, so I'll have to find a way to implement that, but maybe that isn't actually necessary for my case.

Comment: Actually, your solution appears perfect. If the function `f2(t,x,y,z)` returns `nan` values, the only difference would be that your result would return `nan` values, whereas my for loop approach with the `np.nansum` would return a 0, but that is easily accounted for.